# Replace string for exact match with conditions

Tags: java, regex

Sample string

> astabD (tabD) tabD .tabD tabD. (tabD tabD)

I need to replace tabD with something like `temp.tabD` for every of the occurrence in the above string except the first and second one.

For this I tried replaceAll with word boundary

> str.replaceAll("\b"+ "tabD" + "\b","`temp.tabD`"))

Works except for the second occurrence. Would appreciate any help since '(' and ')' are also keywords and only the occurrence of both have to be ignored.

Comment: so ```astabD``` will not be replaced? or will it become ```astemp.tabD```?

Comment: What is the rule here?

Comment: astabD wont be replaced.

Comment: If the rule is to replace the whole word that is not surrounded with parentheses, try something like `.replaceAll("\\b(?<!\\((?=\\w+\\)))tabD\\b", "")`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xGaOW5/1).

Comment: + repetition not allowed inside lookbehind

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could you please post this as an answer. It works. My IDE shows an error for + repetition inside lookbehind. But compiles and runs fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
.replaceAll("\\b(?<!\\((?=\\w+\\)))tabD\\b", "")
```

Or, if `tabD` comes in from user input:

```
String s = "astabD (tabD) tabD .tabD tabD. (tabD tabD)";
String word = "tabD";
String wordRx = Pattern.quote(word);
s = s.replaceAll("(?<!\\w)(?<!\\((?=" + wordRx + "\\)))" + wordRx + "(?!\\w)", "");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xGaOW5/1/).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary (`(?<!\w)` is an unambiguous left word boundary)
- `(?<!\((?=\w+\)))` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if right before the current location there is a `(` that is followed with 1+ word chars (`\w+` is required to match the `tabD` word) followed with `)` (**NOTE**: If your IDE tells you the `+` is inside a lookbehind, it is the IDE bug since the `+` is in a lookahead here and `+` / `*` quantifiers are allowed in lookaheads)
- `tabD`  - the word to find
- `\b` - a word boundary (`(?!\w)` is an unambiguous right word boundary)

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/A3q5Cz):

```
String s = "astabD (tabD) tabD .tabD tabD. (tabD tabD)";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\b(?<!\\((?=\\w+\\)))tabD\\b", ""));
// => astabD (tabD)  . . ( )
```

Comment: @SagarSaxena Not sure what you mean, but `s.replace("(tabD)", "")` will work for a literal. If you want to replace a word from several words inside parentheses, you may use `replaceAll(Pattern.quote(word) + "(?=[^()]*\\))", "")`